# How to convert classification model from fastText to a TensorFlow SavedModel to be used in BigQuery ML?

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery, tensorflow2.0, fasttext

I have a trained model saved from fastText. The model is saved with `model.save_model("model.bin")`
I need to load the model to BigQuery ML and run it there. BigQuery ML allows to import a TensorFlow model and that is why I want to convert my fastText model to a TensorFlow model. I have searched a  lot and am conceived that it can be done but I have not really found a clear explanation on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.